# how do i stream codepipeline/codebuild stdout through an API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-codepipeline

so im trying to run Terraform through CodePipeline. I need to manage a fleet of clusters. It seems CodePipeline is one of the good ways to trigger certain pipelines on some conditions.

I have a very simple requirement - i want to see the terraform execution in real time. i want to expose the CodePipeline run in a way that i can stream this. Is this where EventBridge is used. I tried to look at an EventBridge example here - https://medium.com/hackernoon/monitoring-ci-cd-pipelines-with-amazon-eventbridge-32177e2f2c3e - but it doesnt seem to be streaming run output in real time.

Which event or hook to should i attach to? And is CodePipeline even the right thing to use here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which event or hook to should I attach to?

You're looking at the wrong AWS service. EventBridge is not for streaming log output. It is for discrete events, not a stream.

Your CodePipeline would be using a CodeBuild task to execute Terraform. Your CodeBuild task will be configured to log to AWS CloudWatch Logs. You can view the CloudWatch Logs output in the AWS CloudWatch web console, with the option to poll for new log output.

You can also do the same in a command line console with the `aws logs tail` command, [documented here](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/logs/tail.html).

To do the same thing in your own code you would have to write your code to poll the CloudWatch Logs API in an loop.

> And is CodePipeline even the right thing to use here?

Yes absolutely

Comment: just one added question - filterlogevents is the right api to get the cloudwatch streaming log ?

Comment: If you're trying this via an SDK or API call, you would have to call `filterlogevents` or `getlogevents` over and over in a loop. If you are using the CLI tool, you would call the `tail` command which does that for you.